# How to merge multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have main_dict.

```
main_dict={'name1':{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'name2':{'key1':'value3', 'key2':'value8'} ... }
```

I have 2 other dictionaries which brings some more data to be added in the main_dict.

like,

```
**age_dict= {{'age':'age_value1', 'name': 'name1'}, {'age':'age_value1', 'name': 'name2'}}
gender_dict= {{'gender':'gen_value1', 'name': 'name1'}, {'gender':'gen_value2', 'name': 'name2'}}**
```

Now i would like to make some loops and merge these dictionaries such that
it checks for the same name and takes values from age and gender dictionaries and create keys 'age' , 'gender' and add them into main_dict.

For now i have done this, but i think django can help to do this in a single way:

```
for user in age_dict:
    for key, value in main_dict.iteritems():
        if key == user['name']:
            value['age'] = user['age_value']

for user in gender_dict:
    for key, value in main_dict.iteritems():
        if key == user['name']:
            value['gender'] = user['gen_value']
```

EDIT: Modified age_dict and gender_dict.

Comment: Not sure what django has to do with it, but there's the `update` method on a `dict`: `d1.update(d2)` (or the other way around, depending on for which dictionary you want to override values).

Comment: Ok. This is enlightening, but can we use .update method with conditions like i have to check of the 'name' key.

Comment: You may find `has_key` to be useful as well. e.g. if dict.has_key(key)

Comment: The keys 'age' and 'gender' are not there for sure, i want to add them with their values for each 'name'

Comment: @Lian: has_key is deprecated (and removed in Python 3), use "in": `if key in dict:`

Comment: `age_dict` and `gender_dict` are not valid python (Unhashable Type: dict)

Comment: These are the result of a query with values tag. Are they no dict ?

Comment: Just try to execute `gender_dict= {{'gender':'gen_value1', 'name': 'name1'}, {'gender':'gen_value2', 'name': 'name2'}}` in your favorite python interpreter and see that it does not work.
See my edited answer, I assume you are handling with a list of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General hint: if you are doing something like

```
for key, val in some_dict.iteritems():
    if key == some_value:
       do_something(val)
```

you are most likely *doing it wrong*, because you are not using the dictionaries very purpose: accessing elements by their keys. Instead, do

```
do_something(some_dict[key])
```

and use exceptions if you can't be sure that `somedict[key]` exists.

---

You don't have to interate over dictionaries to find the appropriate key. Just access it directly, that's what dictionaries are for:

```
main_dict={'name1':{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'name2':{'key1':'value3', 'key2':'value8'}}


age_dicts = [{'age':'age_value1', 'name': 'name1'}, 'age':'age_value1', 'name': 'name2'}]
gender_dicts = [{'gender':'gen_value1', 'name': 'name1'}, 'gender':'gen_value2', 'name': 'name2'}]

for dct in age_dicts:
    main_dict[dct['name']]['age'] = dct['age']

for dct in gender_dicts:
    main_dict[dct['name']]['gender'] = dct['gender']
```

---

Specific answer to the pre-edit case:

```
age_dict= {'name1':'age_value1', 'name2':'age_value2'}
gender_dict= {'name1':'gen_value1', 'name2':'gen_value2'}
```

If you are sure that `gender_dict` and `age_dict` provide values for each name, it's as easy as

```
for name, dct in main_dict.iteritems():
   dct['age'] = age_dict[name]
   dct['gender'] = gender_dict[name]
```

If there are names without entries in the other dictionaries, you can use exceptions:

```
for name, dct in main_dict.iteritems():
   try:
       dct['age'] = age_dict[name]
   except KeyError:    # no such name in age_dict
       pass
   try:
       dct['gender'] = gender_dict[name]
   except KeyError:    # no such name in gender_dict
       pass
```

Comment: I am sorry , but there is a change in age_dict and gender_dict. and this way we have to iterate these dict to check the same name

Comment: The current dicts in the question are not valid python.

Answer (score 1):

The setdefault method of dict looks up a key, and returns the value if found. If not found, it returns a default, and also assigns that default to the key.

```
super_dict = {}
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        super_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Also, you might consider using a defaultdict. This just automates setdefault by calling a function to return a default value when a key isn't found.

```
import collections
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        super_dict[k].append(v)
```

Also, as Sven Marnach astutely observed, you seem to want no duplication of values in your lists. In that case, set gets you what you want:

```
import collections
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        super_dict[k].add(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want use `age_dict` and `gender_dict` to enrich the values for the keys in `main_dict`. Well, given [Python guarantees average dict lookup to be constant](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) you are constrained only by the number of keys in `main_dict` and you can reach the enrichment in `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the dictionary:

```
for user_name, user_info in main_dict.items():
  if user_name in gender_dict:
    user_info['gender'] = gender_dict[user_name]
  if user_name in age_dic:
    user_info['age'] = age_dict[user_name]
```

And a fancy function doing this in a generic way:

```
def enrich(target, **complements):
  for user_name, user_info in target.items():
    for complement_key, complemented_users in complements.items():
      if user_name in complemented_users:
        user_info[complement_key] = complemented_users[user_name]

enrich(main_dict, age=age_dict, gender=gender_dict)
```

Even if you see two nested loops, it is more likely the number of users in `main_dict` dominates over the number of complementary dictionaries.